# Unpredictable update in value of the variable

Tags: c++, character, codeblocks, dev-c++

I have been trying to solve this for quite long now . In the given program R is getting updated unpredictably even without touching it which can be seen in the 30th line where I print R is %d . Also after some iterations of the k loop, it is showing unpredictable behaviour. I have no idea what problem is going while the program is executed . Kindly help me with this . Thanks in advance .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int T;
  int R;
  string test;
  scanf("%d", &T);
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < T; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &R);
    printf("Hi R is %d\n", R);
    int j = 1;
    char c, p;
    int k;
    char help[94];
    char b = 33;
    int lop;
    if (R != 0) {
      for (k = 0; k < 94; k++) {
        help[b + k] = 'f';
      }
      printf("R is %d\n", R);
      for (; j <= R; j++) {
        cin >> c >> p;
        printf("C is %c and P is %c\n", c, p);
        help[c] = p;
      }
    }
    cin >> test;
    int size = test.size();
    if (R != 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (help[test.at(i)] != 'f')
          test.replace(i, i, test.at(i), help[test.at(i)]);
      }
    }
    cout << "string till now is " << test;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the long code .
An input output example is

```
5
3
Hi R is 3
R is 1717986918
```

Comment: See [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you post some input/output examples? and btw...you should work on your variable names...

Comment: @NirMH I have edited and provided an input/output example .

Comment: @rightfold I will just edit and make it minimal. Sorry for the large code.

Comment: I've executed your code on VS2012 Win64bit with no issues. i have not observed any change to `R`. on second `R` print it says `R is 3`

Comment: I ran it on DevC++ and CodeBlocks. Both are showing correct for the first R print. But for the second one, R is changing .

Comment: Add `CodeBlocks` and `DevC++` to your tag list - it might be an issue there - i'm not an expert with that library and tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array help is 94 chars but your loop will write past the end of it in help[b+k] = 'f', since b = 33. So, you are basically overwriting memory; it's a coincidence that it is K you notice it for.

```
int main() {
int T;
int R;
string test;
scanf("%d", &T);
int i = 0;
for (; i < T; i++) {
  scanf("%d", &R);
  printf("Hi R is %d\n", R);
  int j = 1;
  char c, p;
  int k;
  char help[94];
  char b = 33;
  int lop;
  if (R != 0) {
    for (k = 0; k < 94; k++) {
      help[b + k] = 'f';  <----------- BOOM
    }
```

Edit: added code to highlight problem

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input but I am trying to store the characters from ascii value 33 to 126 in the help array. And b i.e. space has ascii value 33 . So I am considering 94 chars only for the array. So why is it a problem here.

Comment: Arrays in c++ are always 0 based. So when you declare char help[94], then you get an array of char from 0..93. When you assign something to index 33 + k then you will get an address above 93 when k > 60.

Comment: You want to store 

    help[k] = (char)(b + k);

*Edit: desperately trying to workaround the editor*

Comment: So, if I want to have an array with characters of ascii value from 33 to 126 as indices and the size of the array is 94, how should I do it ?

Comment: Actually I am trying to initialise the array with characters as indices with . For example help[space]='f' . Space has a ascii value 33 . Similarly for others in the range from 33 to 126 .

Comment: Try with a constant offset: 'int HELP_OFFSET = -33;' and then when you access the array: 'help[HELP_OFFSET + char_value] = some_value;'

Comment: For example if char_value is 33 then here HELP_OFFSET+char_value = 0 which is not the character with ascii value 33 i.e. space . But I want space as index . Similarly when k becomes 22 i.e b+k = 65 then I want char['A']='f'. This is what I am trying .Hope you understand now what I am trying to do .

Comment: Well, in general you cannot do that. Arrays in c/c++ are always 0-based. In general you want to either modify indices to reflect this (i.e. by offsetting as hinted above), use a map or dictionary from standard library, or in your particular case make help bigger (i.e char help[33 + k]) - in this case you waste the first 33 chars for nothing, but that is neglible.